# Solr8.0 Error creating document, but why?

Tags: solr

I have a newly installed 8.0 Solr. I can't input my documents.

can it be that, which are causing my problems?

SolrWriter
Error creating document : SolrInputDocument(fields: [id=1,​ name_cn=中国,​ name_en=CHINA])

Comment: Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: There should be a much larger error message after the part you included - it'll contain information about why the document couldn't be created.